# Why does the method change passed array's value

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, oop, pass-by-reference

I am making changes in a local variable and returning it. I think it should print 12 at line no 9.

```
public class HackerEarth {

    int a[]= {3,4,5};
    int b[]=foo(a);

    void display() {
        System.out.println(a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+ " "); //line no 9
        System.out.println(b[0]+b[1]+b[2]+ " ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HackerEarth he=new HackerEarth();
        he.display();
    }
    private int[] foo(int[] a2) {
        int b[]=a2;
        b[1]=7;
        return b;
    }
}
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: A *reference* to the array is passed (by value). You only ever create one array.

Comment: in foo method you are passing a[] reference and later b[1] = 7, you are modifying the array. SO whatever changes you'll do to b[] will be reflected to a[]. Thus a[1] is also 7 and giving you a[0] + a[1] + a[2] =15

Comment: @ayaz, please do not rewrite the question to ask something different. If you have another problem, create another question for that

Comment: Don't edit the question to ask a different question.

Comment: @Andronicus ok, my bad . Actally both are interrelated, so I thought of asking in the same post.

Comment: @ayazhusain yes, you're right, they are quite similar, but you already got 4 answers for the previous one. If you now change the question, all of the answers are not related, from outside none of them answers your question;)

Comment: @Andronicus.. yes, agree.

Comment: @WJS.I didn't get it. What solution you are taking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the reference to the first array to overwrite it's value in `foo` method. To create another array based on values of the passed ones, consider using [`Arrays.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int%5B%5D,int)):

```
private int[] foo(int[] a2) {
    int b[] = Arrays.copyOf(a2, a2.length);
    b[1]=7;
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are changing the second value in the array to 7. You are doing this in the method.

```
    private int[] foo(int[] a2) {
        int b[] = a2; // <-- copying the array reference.
        b[1] = 7; // so changing the second value here.
        return b;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of assigning reference of array a `int b[] = a2;` to array b you can copuy the values of array a to b :

```
private int[] foo(int[] a2) {
    int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a2,a2.length);
    b[1]=7;
    return b;
}
```

**Output**

```
 12
 15
```

Comment: @Andronicus , I didn't copied existing answers simulatneously same answers posted

Comment: Ok, sory for bothering then;>